# Why is swastika in buddhism is in this 卍 format and not in this 卐 format? What is the difference between the two? What is the meaning of each sign?

Tags: theravada, texts, tibetan-buddhism, hinduism

I want to know why swastika is reverse in both the religion and what is the meaning of each sign?
Someone within this forum said below lines on which I want to know what you people have to say on it and I want to know what's right.

> In Buddhism drawing right hand side swastika 卍 (Good, positive, solar aspects, movement clockwise 'with' the currents of Nature) means non-violence, peace.
>   In Hinduism drawing left hand side swastika 卐 (Evil, negative, lunar aspects, movement counter-clockwise 'against' the currents of Nature) means violence.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: It's the same swastika - just from the different side ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Buddhism explains the *dependent origination* of suffering, which is the 'wrong path' ([SN 12.3](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn12.3)).

Conversely, 'dependent cessation' is called the 'right path' ([SN 12.3](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn12.3)).

Dependent origination is often pictorially depicted as spinning clockwise, as follows:

[image]

[image]

The clockwise direction is the direction of 'origination' or 'creation'.

Theistic religions, such as Judaism, Islam & Hinduism worship creation, therefore it is expected they would worship a clockwise swastika.

Where as Buddhism honors cessation rather than creation, i.e., turning back creation.